# SQL Oracle Find who has the max : having count(*) >= all(..) VS having count(*) = (select max(count(*))

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to find which person is the most present in a table. 
I have two working solutions but I don't know if there is any difference between them, and which one to prefer.

Solution 1 : using all

```sql
select numPerson
From nameTable
Group by numPerson
Having count(*)>= all(select count(*) from nameTable group by numPerson);
```

Solution 2 : using max

```sql
select numPerson
From nameTable
Group by numPerson
Having count(*)= (select max(count(*)) from nameTable group by numPerson);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to write this using window functions.  I'm not a fan of the second syntax, nested aggregation functions, because it uses bespoke Oracle functionality -- but Oracle aficionados probably love it.  I would write that as:

```
having count(*)= (select max(cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt from nameTable group by numPerson) p);
```

But that is irrelevant to your question.  In your `having` clause the two are equivalent.

However, there are differences:

The first involves no rows being returned in the subquery:

- The `all` form will return all rows when the subquery returns no values.
- The aggregation form will return no rows when the subquery returns no values.

The second involves `null` values in column used in the `all`:

- The `all` returns no rows.
- The aggregation ignores the `NULL` values if there are any non-`NULL` values.

Because of the nature of your query, "all rows when the subquery returns no values" is the same as "no rows".  And `count(*)` never returns `NULL`. So the two are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So many questions in return ! 
* What are bespoke Oracle functionality ?
* Why would you write the request this way ?

Comment: @Ccile . . . "bespoke" means that it is "customized for Oracle".  That is, functionality specific to Oracle that is not in the standard (and probably not in other databases either).

Comment: #Gordon: window functions (called by Oracle analytic functions) are part of the SQL standard since 2003. Here is a link that claims they are supported by 19 products: https://data-xtractor.com/blog/query-builder/window-functions-support/

Comment: @StewAshton . . . This has nothing to do with window functions.  This is about nesting aggregation functions:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=84fbca49545baf6e7918e7d551c52bd2.

Comment: @Gordon, sorry! For some reason my brain skipped over a handful of words in your second sentence; the result was I misread you completely. I would edit the comment to disown it but apparently it is too late. I'll leave it as is so your correction will not be orphaned. Sorry again!

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh, new English word for me ! Thanks !

Comment: @Ccile . . . It is an interesting word, associated with tailoring.  "Bespoke" is in contrast to "pret-a-porter" clothes ("ready to wear").  Being English, there are lots of synonyms for both.

Answer (score 1):

```
select stats_mode(numperson) from nametable
```

The above will return only one row. Your solutions will return more than one row in case of ties. If you accept Oracle window functions, you can get the ties yet avoid the second "full table scan":

```
select numPerson from (
  select numPerson, count(*) cnt, max(count(*)) over() max_cnt
  from nameTable
  group by numPerson
)
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

Comment: I want to get the ties. Why this solution is better ?

Comment: This solution is more efficient because, as I said, it "avoids the second full table scan". Your solutions scan the table twice, my solution scans the table once. To see the difference, look at the execution plan. Do you know how to do this? Google "DBMS_XPLAN"

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't understand the end of the sentence